# Using Open Graph to define videos on WordPress?

Tags: facebook, wordpress, facebook-opengraph

I would be interested in tagging YouTube videos that I publish on my WordPress blog to be automatically tagged as og:video if they are inserted in a post--is there any plugin or simplified way to do this? I realize I could edit the meta tags for each post, but I'm looking for a more elegant solution to the problem?

Answer (score 1):

This plugin may work for what you're describing: 
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/meta-ographr/